# cryptsetup luksFormat error: Requested offset is beyond real size of device /dev/loop1

Tags: shell, unix, encryption, ubuntu-14.04

I'm getting an error when I try to run the cryptsetup luksFormat command on Ubuntu.Can someone please help me with this issue

Command:
      $ loop_dev= losetup --find
      $ echo YES | cryptsetup -v luksFormat --key-file="/path/to/keyfile" $loop_dev

Error:
        Requested offset is beyond real size of device /dev/loop1.
        Command failed with code 22: Requested offset is beyond real size of device /dev/loop1

This is happening to all the loop devices from /dev/loop0-/dev/loop7

Comment: Hi, Were you able to solve this issue? I'm kinda facing same thing

Comment: Yes, I got this issue resolved.

Comment: I had to unmount all the loop device(existing/previously added) then close all the dmcrypt device (using the cmd - luksClose) and then free all the /dev/loop* devices(example: losetup -d /dev/loop1). After following these steps I was able to recrate the encrypted device succesfully.

Comment: I'm adding this as a comment, not an answer.
This happens when the given loop device does not exist. Try to invoke ''cryptsetup'' with a non-existent loop device and you will see this message.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the only possible workaround is to use the script `cryptmount-setup` to create an encrypted loopback device.